# UItableView performance issue after scrolling for a while

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UItableViewCell that I am creating programmatically inside tableView:CellForRowAtIndexpath that is suffering from poor performance after you have been scrolling for a while.

I initially had it as a custom UITableViewCell inside InterfaceBuilder, However I have no programmatically created this view, which has increased the performance by about 40% however after scrolling say 40 - 100 lines it starts to get very glitchy. I was thinking of working out how to cache the height of the UITableView of Cells however I am now wondering if its a fundamental error in my code. For instance maybe my deque is not working? I am not sure how to check this.

This is what my tableview method looks like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    if ([sortedItemsArray count] > 0) {
        NSDictionary *currentInstallDictionary = [sortedItemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        NSNumber *tempDUP = [currentInstallDictionary objectForKey:@"dup"];
        NSInteger myInteger = [tempDUP integerValue];
        
        if (myInteger == 0) {
            //assign vals to labels
            areaLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, -2.0, 140.0, 35.0)];
            NSString *areaString = [currentInstallDictionary objectForKey:@"area"];
            if ((NSNull *) areaString != [NSNull null]) {
                areaLabel.text = areaString;
            } else {
                areaLabel.text = @" ";
            }
            areaLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
            areaLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            [areaLabel sizeToFit];
            [cell addSubview:areaLabel];
            
            // removed other UIlabel that were here for readability
            
            descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(450.0, 5.0, 140.0, 35.0)];
            NSString *descriptionString = [currentInstallDictionary objectForKey:@"partDesc"];
            if ((NSNull *) descriptionString != [NSNull null]) {
                descriptionLabel.text = descriptionString;
            } else {
                descriptionLabel.text = @" ";
            }
            descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
            descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            [descriptionLabel sizeToFit];
            [cell addSubview:descriptionLabel];
            
            shipmentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(605.0, 5.0, 140.0, 35.0)];
            NSString *shipString = [currentInstallDictionary objectForKey:@"totShip"];
            if ((NSNull *) shipString != [NSNull null]) {
                 shipmentLabel.text = shipString;
            } else {
                shipmentLabel.text = @" ";
            }
            shipmentLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
            shipmentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            [shipmentLabel sizeToFit];
            [cell addSubview:shipmentLabel];
            
            quantityALabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(755.0, 5.0, 50.0, 35.0)];
            NSString *totDryQtyString = [currentInstallDictionary objectForKey:@"totDryQty"];
            if ((NSNull *) totDryQtyString != [NSNull null]) {
                quantityALabel.text = totDryQtyString;
            } else {
                quantityALabel.text = @" ";
            }
            quantityALabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
            quantityALabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            [quantityALabel sizeToFit];
            [cell addSubview:quantityALabel];
            
            quantityBLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(815.0, 5.0, 50.0, 35.0)];
            NSString *totInsQtyString = [currentInstallDictionary objectForKey:@"totInsQty"];
            if ((NSNull *) totInsQtyString != [NSNull null]) {
                quantityBLabel.text = totInsQtyString;
            } else {
                quantityBLabel.text = @" ";
            }
            quantityBLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
            quantityBLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            [quantityBLabel sizeToFit];
            [cell addSubview:quantityBLabel];
            
            

            
            NSString *tDStateAString = [currentInstallDictionary objectForKey:@"totDryStateA"];
            NSString *tDStateBString = [currentInstallDictionary objectForKey:@"totDryStateB"];
            
            fitButtonImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            fitButtonImage.frame = CGRectMake(888.0, 5.0, 35.0, 35.0);
            if (([tDStateAString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([tDStateBString isEqualToString:@"W"])) {
                UIImage *checkedOnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOn.png"];
                [fitButtonImage setImage:checkedOnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [cell addSubview:fitButtonImage];
            } else if (([tDStateAString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([tDStateBString isEqualToString:@"R"])) {
                UIImage *checkedOnDisabledImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOnDisabled.png"];
                [fitButtonImage setImage:checkedOnDisabledImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [cell addSubview:fitButtonImage];
            } else {
                if (![quantityALabel.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
                    UIImage *checkedOffImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOff.png"];
                    [fitButtonImage setImage:checkedOffImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    fitButtonImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                } else {
                    fitButtonImage.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                }
                
            }

            
            NSString *tIStateAString = [currentInstallDictionary objectForKey:@"totInstStateA"];
            NSString *tIStateBString = [currentInstallDictionary objectForKey:@"totInstStateB"];
            
            insButtonImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            insButtonImage.frame = CGRectMake(968.0, 5.0, 35.0, 35.0);
            if (([tIStateAString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([tIStateBString isEqualToString:@"W"])) {
                UIImage *checkedOnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOn.png"];
                [insButtonImage setImage:checkedOnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [cell addSubview:insButtonImage];
            } else if (([tIStateAString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([tIStateBString isEqualToString:@"R"])) {
                UIImage *checkedOnDisabledImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOnDisabled.png"];
                [insButtonImage setImage:checkedOnDisabledImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [cell addSubview:insButtonImage];
            } else {
                UIImage *checkedOffImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckedOff.png"];
                [insButtonImage setImage:checkedOffImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [cell addSubview:insButtonImage];
            }
            
            
            //add lines to cell
            lineBreakOneView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140.0, 0.0, 0.5, 44.0)];
            lineBreakOneView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            [cell addSubview:lineBreakOneView];
            
            lineBreakTwoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(290.0, 0.0, 0.5, 44.0)];
            lineBreakTwoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            [cell addSubview:lineBreakTwoView];
            
            lineBreakThreeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(440.0, 0.0, 0.5, 44.0)];
            lineBreakThreeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            [cell addSubview:lineBreakThreeView];
            
            lineBreakFourView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(590.0, 0.0, 0.5, 44.0)];
            lineBreakFourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            [cell addSubview:lineBreakFourView];
            
            lineBreakFiveView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(745.0, 0.0, 0.5, 44.0)];
            lineBreakFiveView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            [cell addSubview:lineBreakFiveView];
            
            lineBreakSixView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(805.0, 0.0, 0.5, 44.0)];
            lineBreakSixView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            lineBreakSixView.alpha = 0.3;
            [cell addSubview:lineBreakSixView];
            
            lineBreakSevenView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(865.0, 0.0, 0.5, 44.0)];
            lineBreakSevenView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            [cell addSubview:lineBreakSevenView];
            
            lineBreakEightView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(945.0, 0.0, 0.5, 44.0)];
            lineBreakEightView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            lineBreakEightView.alpha = 0.3;
            [cell addSubview:lineBreakEightView];
            
            return cell;
        }
    }
    return cell; // this shouldnt happen if the data is correct
}
```

There are actually a few more labels in there also, so it's quite a complicated UITableViewCell which I would like to add a few more images to etc... but before I can do that I will need to sort out the performance issues I am suffering from.

Comment: Wow, your cellForRow method should only be a few lines long. Maybe 5 or 10 lines. You shouldn't be creating stuff in there either. If you want a custom UITableViewCell then create a subclass and use that instead. Also, you're adding labels to the cells every time. If you are adding stuff to the cell in here then it should only be done once. In subsequent calls it should use the labels that you added previously. (Which is why you should use a subclass). This is why it is slow. After scrolling 100 lines through the table each cell will have 10-15 instances of every label on it.

Comment: Okay thanks.. now that you mention it it makes complete sense that im just adding UILable ontop of UILabel... Ill invstigate su classing that custom cell now

Answer (score 1):

Things like: `[cell addSubview:areaLabel];` (where `areaLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init..`) are not ok inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, unless you're doing it inside the `if (cell == nil)`. In your case, you're creating and adding labels continously to your cells, so after scrolling a while, your actual cells will contain a multitude of labels/subviews (some will probably be hidden behind others).

You need to create and add those subviews just once, and afterwards only set/refresh their content.

As @Fogmeister mentioned, it's best if you create a custom cell instead (separate class in which you do all your customization).

Comment: I have another question, How would I pass the data in currentInstallDictionary to the subclassed UITableViewCell?

Comment: @HurkNburkS you can create a simple property for it (let's call it `@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *content`). In your `setContent:` method (inside your custom cell class), you'd be able to refresh the content of the cell's controls, in a similar manner as you do now (just make sure not to create any new subviews and use the ones created during initialization).